# How to Access System Log on Mac

Tags: macos

I have this screenshot someone posted of System Log but I have no idea how to reach there.

[image]

Comment: `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`

Answer (score 11):

If somebody is looking for how to access it without console.app then the files are in `/var/log`

Answer (score 3):

The "Files" are located in the `~/Library/Logs/`. To see a different user's logs, you have to sign in with that user's login.

To see the "Diagnostic and Usage Information" section, it's located in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`. Each crash log file is named with the name of the app or process that crashed, and the date.  And sometimes the same log is shown in 2 or 3 places.

Answer (score 2):

This screenshot is of the Console application. You can find it in /Applications/Utilities/Console.app